# What are the correct uses and differences of KVO and NSNotificationCenter?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter, key-value-observing

Both KVO and NSNotificationCenter can deal with a value change. What's the difference between them? What's the correct use of them?

Comment: was my answer good enough? you still got open questions? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**KVO** is specifically for the change of `properties`.

**NSNotificationCenter** can be used in a much broader context for all kinds of notifications, not only those dealing with property value changes. Plus, you can create your own notifications to send out to any other interested object that formerly subscribed to this notification as an observer.

To create your custom notification use:
`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"somethingHappened" object:nil];`

Another class can then subscribe to this notification with this code:
`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(somethingHappenedSomewhere:) name:@"somethingHappened" object:nil];`

Whenever the method `somethingHappenedSomewhere:` will be called with the `NSNotification` as an argument.

Comment: To expand on this answer...NSNotifications can also be sent across applications. I like to think of Notifications as being useful where some object may or may not be listening for the change, but it's important to broadcast that change.

Comment: well, that's not true is it? how would that work? app A sends a notification and app B receives it while being in the background and subsequently performs custom operations? that's definitely not possible,... maybe you are talking about `UILocalNotification`...?! those are again a whole other story.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I'm referring to NSDistributedNotificationCenter on OS X, I guess that's not available on iOS.

Comment: all right then and thanks for the hint!!! :)